# w3-table the column unequal width size

Tags: html, css, html-table, w3.css

I'm using w3css with class w3-table.
I set the width for each "td" with width 35px and height 35px.
I found out that the width still changes according to the text.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<style>
    .box{
        width: 35px;
        height: 35px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .yellow {
        background-color: yellow !important;
    }
</style>
<body>

<table class="w3-table">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="box yellow">20</td>
         <td class="box yellow">1000</td>
         <td class="box yellow">2</td>
         <td class="box yellow">10</td>
         <td class="box yellow">1000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="box yellow">&nbsp;</td>
         <td class="box yellow">&nbsp;</td>
         <td class="box yellow">&nbsp;</td>
         <td class="box yellow">&nbsp;</td>
         <td class="box yellow">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Whereby I attach the result output as below:

[image: Output Result]

There have A, B, C, D, E column labelled for easy me to explain.
A with text 20
B with text 1000
C with text 2
D with text 10
E with text 1000

A and D column have two digit text ie 20 and 10 respectively.
I expected A and D have the same width but the output result showed A width slightly bigger than D. I can conclude that the first column always slight bigger compare to other columns.
I also notice that the column width change according to the number of text.
Example 1000 in column B and E width bigger 2 in column C.

May I know how to make sure the column width able to maintain a fixed size ratio in each column while being able to maintain a responsive web page?

I appreciate if you can give me some hints on this.

Comment: Your idea is a mistake. Why you give a fixed 35px width for each column, when your table has 100% width? This is the cause of your problem. Use percents and min/max-width property when needed.

Comment: I appreciate if you can show me a correct idea with altered source code. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this change

```
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow !important;
    max-width:35px;
}
```

This will make the width equal for all the columns even it has large value. Here is the running example:

```css
.box{
     width: 35px;
     height: 35px;
     border: 1px solid black;
 }
 .yellow {
     background-color: yellow !important;
     max-width:35px;
 }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>W3.CSS</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <table class="w3-table">
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td class="box yellow">20</td>
             <td class="box yellow">1000</td>
             <td class="box yellow">289834595</td>
             <td class="box yellow">10</td>
             <td class="box yellow">1000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td class="box yellow">&nbsp;</td>
             <td class="box yellow">&nbsp;</td>
             <td class="box yellow">&nbsp;</td>
             <td class="box yellow">&nbsp;</td>
             <td class="box yellow">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It fix the width problem. By the way, is it possible to fix the first column padding left too?

Comment: Can you be more specific, couldn't get your question. @HenryLoke

Comment: By the way @HenryLoke if the answer fixed your problem, you can mark it as accepted using the tick.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your css file

```
table{
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 300px;
```

}

here's the link http://codepen.io/myco27/pen/oBKWYq

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change css of box class from 35px to 20%

```
.box{
   width: 20%;
   height: 35px;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.
The number of column will change either 3, 4, or 5 columns.
We cant  fix 20% if 5 row and become 25% if 4 row and etc.

Comment: if you have dynamic columns. Just try to add following style

.w3-table {
table-layout: fixed;
}